# Use dataframes for fill another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 76 dataframes, here is one :

```
    Unnamed: 0            0          1
0            0   Nutriments  Quantités
1            1    Protéines      0.4 g
2            2      Lipides      0.2 g
3            3     Glucides     11.3 g
4            4          Eau       86,5
5            5       Fibres      1.2 g
6            6   Vitamine C      18 mg
7            7  Vitamine B1    0.08 mg
8            8  Vitamine B6    0.09 mg
9            9    Magnésium      15 mg
10          10    Potassium     146 mg
11          11    Phosphore      11 mg
```

And I have an other dataframe :

```
Manganèse  Calcium  Eau  ...  Vitamine B3  Vitamine B9  Magnésium
Nom                                   ...                                     
Abricot            NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Acérola            NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Airelles           NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Ananas             NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Argousier          NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
               ...      ...  ...  ...          ...          ...        ...
Rhubarbe           NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Roquette           NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Tomate             NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Topinambour        NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Yuzu               NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
```

My list of dataframes is a list of vegetables and fruits. For example, the dataframe "Pineapple" (Ananas in French) must fill in the general dataframe.

I need a result like :

```
Manganèse  Calcium  Eau  ...  Vitamine B3  Vitamine B9  Magnésium
Nom                                   ...                                     
Abricot            NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Acérola            NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Airelles           NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Ananas             86,5     NaN  ...               NaN          15         NaN
Argousier          NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
               ...      ...  ...  ...          ...          ...        ...
Rhubarbe           NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Roquette           NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Tomate             NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Topinambour        NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
Yuzu               NaN      NaN  NaN  ...          NaN          NaN        NaN
```

So I need to fill the general dataframe with the corresponding lines. The rows of my small dataframe are the columns of my general dataframe. And there is not on all the small dataframes the same number of "columns" as in the general dataframe.

Now I have a dict = `{"apple": df1, "apricot":df2 etc}`. I have :

```
dicttest["Ananas"]
Out[317]: 
   Unnamed: 0           0         1
0           0         Eau    88.9 g
1           1    Glucides       9 g
2           2     Lipides    0.15 g
3           3   Protéines       1 g
4           4      Fibres       2 g
5           5  Vitamine A     91 UI
6           6  Vitamine C    240 mg
7           7     Calcium     15 mg
8           8     Energie   25 kcal
9           9     Energie  104.5 kJ
```

in 'Ananas' value.

Do you have a solution to make what I need?

Comment: The list of 76 dataframes - how it defined? In a dict? 76 global variables? Something else?

Comment: It's a list : listdataframe = ["my 76 dataframes"]. So I have 76 different dataframe in 'listdataframe'

Comment: And how do you know which item in the list represents which fruit?

Comment: It's in alphabetical order, the fisrt DF is 'Abricot', the second is "Acérola" etc. 
Maybe that's a bad choice?

Comment: I would probably put them in a dict: {"apple": df1, "apricot": df2, etc.}. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do that using `pd.concat` and 'pivot`:

```
dfs = []
for k, v in dicttest.items():
    v["fruit"] = k
    dfs.append(v)
    
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
df = df[[2, 3, "fruit"]] # you may have to change the names of the columns 2 and 3, 
                         # based on the column names in your data
df.columns = ["item", "amt", "fruit"]
res = pd.pivot_table(df, index="fruit", columns="item", aggfunc=",".join)
```

The output is:

```
            amt                                                                        
item    Calcium     Eau Energie Fibres Glucides Lipides Protéines Vitamine A Vitamine C
fruit                                                                                  
ananas    15 mg  88.9 g      []    2 g      9 g  0.15 g       1 g      91 UI     240 mg
apricot   12 mg  88.9 g      []    5 g     12 g  0.12 g       3 g     100 UI     180 mg
```

Comment: In my pincripal datafram, the index is the column 'Nom', it's a probleme for you code ? Because I can't run it correctly

Comment: Do you mean you want the index of the result to be named 'nom'? Or that my code fails with an error?

Comment: Y i can't use your code, omg it's so difficult haha, i try other